# Spring boot webflux annotated controller aspect trying to log the request Mono

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, aop

So I have this around aspect applied to my controller method to log the request and response which works fine if I do not wrap the request in a Mono-

```
   @PostMapping(
            value = TRANSACTION_INSIGHTS_RETRIEVALS_PATH,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @AuditLogEvent(logEventType = LogEventTypeEnum.TRA_REQUEST_RESPONSE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<TransactionInsights>> retrieveTransactionInsights(@Valid @RequestBody TransactionInsightsData transactionInsightsData) {
        return Mono.just(transactionInsightsData)
                .flatMap(request -> {
                    Optional<String> brand = retrieveBrand(request);
                    return transactionInsightsService.retrieveTransactionInsights(request, brand);
                })
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
```

My aspect -

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Order(3)
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuditLogEventAspect {

    private final AuditEventManager auditEventManager;

    @Around("@annotation(auditLogEvent) && args(request)")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, AuditLogEvent auditLogEvent, Object request) throws Throwable {

        Mono result = (Mono) joinPoint.proceed();
        return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> result
                .doOnSuccess(o -> {
                    logSuccessExit(auditLogEvent, ctx.<Map<String, String>>get(CONTEXT_MAP), request, o)
                            .subscribe(auditEvent -> {
                                log.info("auditEvent {}", auditEvent);
                            });
                })
                .doOnError(o -> {
                    logErrorExit(auditLogEvent, ctx.<Map<String, String>>get(CONTEXT_MAP), request, (Exception) o)
                            .subscribe(auditEvent -> {
                                log.info("auditEvent {}", auditEvent);
                            });
                })
                .map(o -> result)
        );
    }

    private Mono<AuditEvent> logErrorExit(AuditLogEvent auditLogEvent, Map<String, String> contextMap, Object request, Exception error) {
        log.info("TRA request: {}", request);
        log.info("TRA error response: {}", error.getMessage());
        AuditEvent initialAuditEvent = auditEventManager.createAuditLogEvent(auditLogEvent, contextMap, request);
        return auditEventManager.saveExceptionEvent(initialAuditEvent, error);
    }

    private Mono<AuditEvent> logSuccessExit(AuditLogEvent auditLogEvent, Map<String, String> contextMap, Object request, Object response) {
        log.info("TRA request: {}", request);
        log.info("TRA response: {}", response);
        AuditEvent initialAuditEvent = auditEventManager.createAuditLogEvent(auditLogEvent, contextMap, request);
        return auditEventManager.saveSuccessEvent(initialAuditEvent, response);
    }


}
```

But ideally I'd like to wrap my request in a Mono like so -

```
@PostMapping(
            value = TRANSACTION_INSIGHTS_RETRIEVALS_PATH,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @AuditLogEvent(logEventType = LogEventTypeEnum.TRA_REQUEST_RESPONSE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<TransactionInsights>> retrieveTransactionInsights(@Valid @RequestBody Mono<TransactionInsightsData> transactionInsightsData) {
        return transactionInsightsData
                .flatMap(request -> {
                    Optional<String> brand = retrieveBrand(request);
                    return transactionInsightsService.retrieveTransactionInsights(request, brand);
                })
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
```

How can I change my aspect to work with arg Mono? I am new to reactive and webflux and learning so what am I missing?

Comment: Don't misuse tags and the mono tag is for something else.

Comment: @LexLi, Sorry I thought it was for the reactive type, my bad will look properly next time.